# Send DataSet data to elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-flink

I'm trying to send some data from a DataSet into elasticsearch using the new elasticsearch connector but I can't find any resources besides the ones for datastream structure here :

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html

My **Dataset** is a dataset of row (from a sql query), this is the content :

```
199947,6
199958,3
199964,2
199985,2
```

I've created a static nested class which implements **ElasticsearchSinkFunction** :

```
public static class NumberOfTransactionsByBlocks implements ElasticsearchSinkFunction<Row> {

    public void process(Row element, RuntimeContext ctx, RequestIndexer indexer) {
        indexer.add(createIndexRequest(element));

    }

    public IndexRequest createIndexRequest(Row element) {
        Map<String, String> json = new HashMap<>();
        json.put("block_number", element.getField(0).toString());
        json.put("numberOfTransactions", element.getField(1).toString());

        return Requests.indexRequest()
                .index("nbOfTransactionsByBlocks")
                .type("count-transactions")
                .source(json);
    }
}
```

And then my problem is that I don't know how to send an instance of my inner class...

```
DataSet<Row> data = tableEnv.toDataSet(sqlResult, Row.class);
List<HttpHost> httpHosts = new ArrayList<>();
httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 9200, "http"));
httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("10.2.3.1", 9200, "http"));

Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
config.put("bulk.flush.max.actions", "1");   // flush inserts after every event
config.put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch"); // default cluster name


data.output(new ElasticsearchSink<>(config, httpHosts, new NumberOfTransactionsByBlocks()));
```

I have an error when I instantiate ElasticsearchSink it says :

> cannot infer arguments

But when I do specify the type (Row) it says :

> ElasticsearchSink(java.util.Map,
>   java.util.List,
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkFunction,
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ActionRequestFailureHandler,
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch6.RestClientFactory)'
>   has private access in
>   'org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch6.ElasticsearchSink'

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently (1.6.0) [four different](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.6.0/flink-connectors) connectors provided by Flink for ElasticSearch.

- [v1.x](https://git.io/fARnD): `flink-connector-elasticsearch_2.11`
- [v2.x](https://git.io/fARny): `flink-connector-elasticsearch2_2.11`
- [v5.x](https://git.io/fARnQ): `flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.11`
- [v6.x](https://git.io/fARn7): `flink-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11`

Make sure you include the correct maven dependency to your project.

> ...has *private access* in `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.`**`elasticsearch6`**`.ElasticsearchSink`

Now, guessing from the trace you shared, it looks like you are using the dependency for `v6.x`. Looking at the [source](https://git.io/fARnh), it suggests that they have moved the constructor to `private` and added a [`Builder`](https://git.io/fARcI) <sup>[[commit]](https://git.io/fARcU)</sup>

So, to add an [`ElasticsearchSink`](https://git.io/fARcZ), you need something like:

```
data.output(
  new ElasticsearchSink.Builder<>(httpHosts, new NumberOfTransactionsByBlocks())
    .setBulkFlushMaxActions(1)
    .build());
```

Also, the import would be

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch6.ElasticsearchSink;
```